# ¿Como puedo actualizar un datagrid?

Tags: c#

Quiero actualizar un `datagrid`, quizas se puede solo con este codigo:

`this.almacenTableAdapter.Fill(this.almacenDataSet.almacen);`

Quiero actualizar el `datagrid` despues de haber hecho una modificacion o agregar un nuevo registro a la base de datos.

Comment: has intentado con .Refresh();

Comment: si, ya intente con:ese pero nada

Comment: revisa esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21299016/how-to-refresh-or-show-immediately-in-datagridview-after-inserting

Comment: una solucion rapida seria crear una funcion para recargar todo es decir mandar a consultar a la bd tus datos y estos cargar en la datagrid.. y cada vez que hagas un insert...update..delete.. mandas a llamar a esta funcion !!

Comment: osea que quito este dataset del datagrid:
> this.almacenTableAdapter.Fill(this.almacenDataSet.almacen);
y hago una consulta directa a la bd??

Comment: seria mejor que agregues tu codigo

Comment: pues es que esa linea de codigo que puse se agrega automaticamente, cuando relacionas el datagrid con el dataset

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar vaciar el datagrid y después volverlo a llenar

```
dgridview.datasource = null;
dgridview.Databind();
```

Comment: no ya lo he intentado, y no funciona, a menos que lo este poniendo en un lagar donde no corresponde, ¿si va en el load?

Comment: No, no va en el load, va justo despues de que modificas un valor del datagrid, preferiblemente en un evento de cambio.

Comment: entonces, una ultima duda, como le puedo hacer para referenciar el datagrid en otro formulario??

Comment: Es como te comenta @NaCl, tienes que hacerlo justo después de que hagas el insert o update a la bd, y para acceder a un control de un formulario a otro, tienes que hacerlo público, es decír, seleccionas el dataGridView, das click derecho, propiedades - Modifiers, y cambias el private por public, entonces ahora haces una instancia desde el formulario que quieres accesar a ese control